# Rails 4 Rspec TimeZone issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having trouble with a failing test.

In my application.rb I have the following:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

In one of my models I have a check_in column. I set it to the following:

```
Time.now + 30.days
```

In my tests I set a variable like the following:

```
thirty_days = Time.now + 30.days
```

I then compare the check_in to the thirty_days variable.

The problem I have is the check_in column in the db is always ahead by one day.

I cannot figure out how to get these days lined up for my test.

For example, if I add puts to my tests:

Time.now + 30.days will output: 2014-06-03 14:29:51 -0700
check_in will output: 2014-06-04 14:29:51 -0700

Please advise.

Comment: just as a side note, you can do `30.days.from_now`. other than that, does not make a lot of sense. did you inspect what get's written to your db? what db is it anyways? did you have a look into the raw data in the db?

Comment: Thanks for the 30.days.from_now. That is cleaner. I'm still having the problem. The db I'm using is mysql. The actual record in the db is: 2014-06-05 00:54:06  When I print it to terminal it's Wed, 04 Jun 2014 17:54:06 PDT -07:00. When I print 30.days.from_now in my tests it's Tue, 03 Jun 2014 17:55:58 PDT -07:00  I am getting three different dates.

Comment: Here is a blog post I did on working with timezones with rails - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - you might find it helpful? You probably want to use something like Timecop in your rspec tests - https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Comment: For some reason the issue was calling the ActiveRecord .update method after calling .update_column I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here, but perhaps your SQL server is converting time zone also (rails does that already and store dates in UTC format).

Check your sql server timezone setting (for mysql it's `SELECT @@system_time_zone`) and see to change it to UTC, then run your test again and see if it works

Comment: Thanks. I set my mysql server to use '+00:00'. I still have the same problem. What's stored in the db is off by a day.